# Should the parent's context be used when retrieving the LayoutInflater from an ArrayAdatper's GetView method?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater, getview

I'm trying reduce redundant calls to `LayoutInflater.FromContext` from within the `GetView` method of an `ArrayAdapter`, so I created a private `LayoutInflater` member `_li` and initialized it in the constructor.

**However, would it be safer to use the context of the `parent` view from within`GetView`?**

```
var li = LayoutInflater.FromContext(parent.Context);
view = li.Inflate(_layoutId, parent, false);
```

**ArrayAdapter**

```
public class StuffAdapter : ArrayAdapter<Stuff>
{
    private readonly int _layoutId;

    //private readonly Context _context;
    private readonly LayoutInflater _li;

    public StuffAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, List<Stuff> stuff) 
        : base(context, layoutId, stuff)
    {
        _layoutId = layoutId;

        //_context = context;
        _li = LayoutInflater.FromContext(context);
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (view == null)
        {
            //var li = LayoutInflater.FromContext(_context);
            view = _li.Inflate(_layoutId, parent, false);
        }

        // ...

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs to get called everytime differently otherwise how will it inflate multiple data what you are doing here will literally destroy the purpose and functioning of an adapter, i would suggest you stop right there.

Comment: Why you want to reduce redundant calls to LayoutInflater.FromContext from within the GetView method of an ArrayAdapter? I do not advice you to do that, because when your want to update your listvew with `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged`, it will call `GetView`, when use `_li.Inflate `, you should make sure `LayoutInflater` not recycled.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I figured doing so may have performance benefits, though your argument compels to me to do otherwise, thanks.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Should a reference to `_context` also not be kept for the same reason, and should I use `parent.Context` instead? They both look to be the same `ContextThemeWrapper` at a breakpoint, but will this always be the case?

Comment: Based on my research, that's ok, but I suggest you test it.